# Protected Override - TextBox Personalizado

Tags: c#

Tengo un inconveniente con un control `TextBox` personalizado que he creado y al cual le agregue varios eventos entre los cuales esta el **`KeyPress`** en el cual valido formato moneda, hasta ahí funciona todo bien.

Mi problema es que al momento de querer adicionar validaciones especificas al control en los proyectos que heredan de este, es como si no reconociera los eventos creados en el control.

Ej: el control valida que la cadena ingresada sea numérica: Ok

A parte si quiero validar que no contenga el numero 5 en el proyecto donde lo herede, no lo reconoce.

```
public class CajaDeTexto : TextBox
{
    protected  override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (IsEnter(e))
            {
                this.SelectionStart = this.Text.Length;
                Tab();
            }
            if (EJ_Mayúsculas) { KeyPressMayusculas(e); }
            if (EJ_SoloNumero) { KeyPressNumeros(ref e); }
            if ((EJ_Dinero) | (EJ_ValorMinimo != 0 | EJ_ValorMaximo != 0) | (EJ_Decimales)) { KeyPressDinero(ref e); }
            if (EJ_Cedula) { KeyPressIdentificacion(ref e); }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { throw ex; }

    }
}
```

En el proyecto donde uso el control, no reconoce algo como esto:

```
private void cajaDeTexto1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    //Ejemplo
    if(e.KeyChar ==(char)Keys.Enter)
    {
        Guardar();
    }
}
```

Comment: No tengo completamente claro lo que estás tratando de hacer. Trata de suministrarnos un [mcve]. Nota aparte, no es necesario tener un `try-catch` que simplemente atrapa y vuelva a lanzar la excepción sin hacer nada con ella. Es mas, no es correcto de volver a lanzar una excepción haciendo `throw ex;`. Esto hace que piredas parte del valioso stack trace. Mas bien, la manera correcta es `throw;`.

Comment: Intenta poner en `cajaDeTexto1_KeyPress` `e.Handled=false`, para que de esa manera despues de ejecutar el código de tu evento llame al manejador del control. Aunque tu pregunta la verdad no está muy clara, sigue el enlace de @sstan para darnos un ejemplo mas completo.

Comment: Que quiere decir que no lo reconoce??? no ejecuta esa parte del codigo?

Comment: es correcto, no la ejecuta, es mas no lo detecta

Answer (score 1):

Sergio, juraría que el problema es que te estás olvidando de llamar a la implementación del método `OnKeyPress()` de la clase base, que es la que se encargará de invocar a todos los suscriptores del evento `KeyPress`. Tal como lo tienes, la única validación que se realizará es la que has implementado tú en `CajaDeTexto`.

Modifica tu implementación de OnKeyPress y añade:

```
base.OnKeyPress(e);
```

Answer (score 0):

Una solución alterna es manejar el evento del lado del cliente.

En la declaración de tu `TextBox` poner el evento `onkeypress="return EnterKey(event)"` para que quede algo como esto:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtBuscar" onkeypress="return EnterKey(event)"></asp:TextBox>
```

Y al inicio de tu página delcarar la función `EnterKey(evt)` en un segmento de código de **JavaScript** para que quede algo como esto:

```
<script>
    function EnterKey(evt) {
        if (window.event.keyCode == 13)
            __doPostBack('<%=cajaDeTexto1.UniqueID%>', "");
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Estas asumiendo q esta en ASP.NET, y nunca dijo algo asi. Puede ser cualquier cosa.